# Wordpress on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I currently have a web application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. It is costing me around $16 per month. Next I would like a have a Wordpress website. I would like the Wordpress website to scale well according to traffic volume. I have also read about AWS CDN CloudFormation which increases the loading speed of the website. I would like the Wordpress website to load fast.

I was thinking that if I add the Wordpress website to the existing environment for AWS Elastic Beanstalk, it could be more cost effective. Am I right here or am I on the wrong track ? If I am wrong, what is the most economical way for me to host Wordpress website on AWS, given that I currently have a Beanstalk application and I would like both autoscaling and speed for the website ?

Comment: A good place to ask WordPress questions is: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think WordPress can scale across multiple computers. It expects to run from one only one computer (instance).

One way to scale WordPress is to move its database to a separate instance, or preferably use Amazon RDS for the database. You can then scale the compute instance and the database separately according to where you find a resource bottleneck.

Using Amazon CloudFront in front of a WordPress site can offload content, especially where "time to live" (TTL) settings are used appropriately to allow static content to be cached in CloudFront. Alternatively, you could store static content in Amazon S3 rather than serving it directly from the WordPress server.

**Bottom line:** Don't put WordPress in Elastic Beanstalk. They are designed for different purposes.

A simple and low-cost place to host WordPress is on an [Amazon Lightsail](https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en_us/all) instance. However, if you wish to scale-up the system, it might be easier to run directly on Amazon EC2.